# Not able to catch SIGINT signal in a multithreaded program

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <signal.h>

sigset_t set;
int sigint_signal = 0;
pthread_t monitor_thread, demo_thread;
pthread_mutex_t m = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

void *monitor()
{

    while(1)
    {
        sigwait(&set, NULL);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&m);
        printf("__SIGINT received__\n");
        sigint_signal = 1;
        pthread_cancel(demo_thread);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&m);
    }

}

void *demo_function(){
    while(1){
        pthread_mutex_lock(&m);
        fprintf(stdout, "__Value of SIGNAL FLAG %d:__\n",sigint_signal);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&m);
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main(){

    sigemptyset(&set);
    sigaddset(&set,SIGINT);
    pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK,&set,0);

    pthread_create(&monitor_thread, 0, monitor, NULL);
    pthread_create(&demo_thread, 0, demo_function, NULL);

    pthread_join(demo_thread, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

`monitor_thread` is the thread that is continuously running to catch the `SIGINT` signal. On receiving the signal it must cancel the other thread and end. 
SIGINT is getting received, this can be verified with the value of the variable `sigint_signal` which becomes `1` once the signal is received.But `pthread_cancel` is not getting executed, because once the value of `sigint_signal` is changed to `1`, the `demo_thread` keeps on running.Please help.

Comment: command used by me to compile is `gcc -g -Wall filename -o executable -lpthread`.

Comment: You really shouldn't rely on `pthread_cancel` at all.  You should make your loop in the thread function read the variable which is assigned by the signal handler, and terminate itself when that is set.

Comment: Thanks @JohnZwinck, the suggestion worked for, but just wanted to ask why not rely on pthread_cancel.

Answer (score 1):

Read the documentation: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_cancel.3.html

There you will see that `pthread_cancel` is not guaranteed to instantly kill the thread, but rather that it depends on the state of that thread.  By default, cancellation can only occur at cancellation points, which do include `write()` which may indirectly include `printf()`.

Anyway, the real solution is to not use `pthread_cancel` at all, and instead use `sigint_signal` as the `while` loop condition in `demo_function`.

As for why `pthread_cancel` is a bad idea, this is because in general, functions are usually not written in a way that they are prepared to die.  It's hard to reason about resource management in a context where execution might be terminated asynchronously.